# "Documents on XXXX's iPhone " folder opens up when I plug in my iPhone

Tags: 11.10, mount, automount, folder, iphone

Everytime I plug my iPhone into my computer (Ubuntu 11.10) a folder pops up titled "Documens on Jamie's iPhone."

How do I stop this?

Initially it asked me what I wanted to do,but I must have hit something on accident to choose to open a folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this question - I can't figure out how to stop the 'Documents on iPhone' folder from opening automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils;idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't solve the problem. The folder still opens automatically.